# text file inside class folder, yet cannot find it

Tags: java

[image]

As you can see, the file is right inside the same folder where the class file is. While I tried to have it print the path to it, that is a bummer because no matter what name I type it will always type a full path to that invented file name. The file is comma separated, that I copied pasted into gedit and tried all kinds of extensions, csv, txt and no extension.

What I am trying to do is import it into an array, but the error is clear, no such file or directory.

Comment: Is your file located in `/home/a/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/productoscoma.txt?` For me it looks as if it is located in `/home/a/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication2/src/main/java/javaaplication2/productoscoma.txt` Please, click on `files` (left column), unfold and make a screenshot again.

Comment: Are you sure this file exists ? Is it not inside some `src` folder ? And even then, it's a really poor way to refer to a file. Why can't you just put it inside your Documents folder and try to access it with the full absolute path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place files that are needed by your program in the classpath of your application so that they will get packaged in your JAR file. You can then read them with `getResourceAsStream()` Here's an idea of how that would work.

```
public class ArrayMain {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(ArrayMain.class.getResourceAsStream("numbers.txt"));
    String[] numbers = in.nextLine().split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

}

The file numbers.txt is a simple file that looks like this:

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 2):

You can try getting the path of the root folder from `System.getProperty()`. Then just append underlying folder names till the required filename.

```
private static String CLASS_PATH = System.getProperty("user.dir");
public static String FILE_PATH= CLASS_PATH + File.separator + "Source Packages"+ File.separator + "javaapplication2"+ File.separator + "pedidos.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use relative paths to get files packaged with your application, it's dirty and senseless.

Path are relative to the folder in which was launched the **java process**. It's (usually) not your application source directory and never you file.java directory.

Even then, it's a terrible practice to put files (resources) inside your application source code. Because your java files needs to be compilated (and often packaged into a jar), the current architecture is likely to have no more meaning once packaged.

If you want to refer to a file on your computer, put it in a sensible folder (like /user/documents) and get it with its absolute path.

If you want the file to be packaged with your application, put it in a resource folder, package it in a jar and get the path with a `classpath://` scheme.

Answer (score -1):

The file needs to be placed at the root folder of your project.